# Open input dialog via script on x server

Tags: shell-script, raspbian, x-server, dialog

I want to make a script with an if that only runs if the user Input the Right password.

Like this:

```
Some Code..
if(Input == "password"){
    Do something
}
More Code..
```

Everything runs on a x Server with matchbox-window-Manager, so not on a console.

Whats a the best way to open a Input Dialog?

If the Input gets checked to equal a user Password its fine too, i just need a very simple password check dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Zenity:

```
sudo apt-get install zenity
```

Then to get a password do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Some Code..."
read Input < <(zenity --password --title="Enter your password")
if [[ "$Input" = "password" ]]; then
    echo "Do something"
fi
```